# Confusion with modulo operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, modulo

i recently asked for a quick solution to a script that changed the background color on each click. the color being from an array. In the first solution, I had to click twice after the first loop to restart it again. In the second solution, it finally worked with one click presumably because of the modulo operator in action. Even after thorough inspection i couldn't bring myself to understand how it worked. here is the code below:-

```
//SCRIPT

 let backgrounds = ['red', 'royalblue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow'], i = 0
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[i%backgrounds.length];
    i++;
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most used property of modulo is that it's circular. meaning that it will go from 0 to x (y%x) and then jumps back to zero. I'ts a good practice to use it when there is a need to set some boundaries, or in your case, to fetch valid values from array with constant length.

Answer (score 1):

`a % b` does whole-number division of `a` by `b` and takes the remainder as its result. For instance, `0 % 5` is `0` because `0 / 5` is `0` remainder `0`. `1 % 5` is `1` because whole-number division of `1 / 5` is `0` remainder `1`. Eventually we get to `5 % 5` which gives us `1` remainder `0`. That's why `i % backgrounds.length` yields `0` (going back to the beginning of the array) when `i` is `0`, `5`, `10`, `15`, and so on.

This illustration may help:

```js
let backgrounds = ['red', 'royalblue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow'];
let i = 0;

for (let counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter) {
    console.log(i, backgrounds[i % backgrounds.length]);
    ++i;
}
```

```css
.as-console- wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

When I do this, I typically do the `%` on the increment rather than the use:

```
console.log(i, backgrounds[i]);
i = (i + 1) % backgrounds.length;
```

That sets `i` back to `0` when it reaches `5`.

But both ways work (well...the first one fails if `i` becomes insanely large, but that's rarely an issue).